# How to have a url as image name in a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to write a docker-compose file that will build and push a versioned (1.0, 1.1...) and latest build of my image to my local v2 docker registry. However when I run `docker-compose build` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

I found a lot of people complaining about this error for many different reasons, in my case it has nothing to do with permissions or weather or not the docker service is running, I narrowed it down to my image naming having a URL on it (the URL of my local registry), I know that because if I name my image normally (like '/app:latest'), then the commands runs fine. So how can I have a URL as the image name?

Here is what I'm trying to do (docker-compose.yaml):

```yaml
version: "3.8"

x-marvin-backend: &default-marvin-backend
  container_name: marvin_backend
  build: ./marvin-api
  image: "http://my_registry_url:5000/marvin/backend:latest"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  networks:
    - backend

x-marvin-frontend: &default-marvin-frontend
  container_name: marvin_frontend
  image: http://my_registry_url:5000/marvin/frontend:latest
  build:
    context: ./marvin-front
    args:
      - REACT_APP_SERVICES_HOST=http://marvin_backend:3000/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  networks:
    - backend
  depends_on:
    - backend

services:
  backend: *default-marvin-backend

  backend_versioned:
      << : *default-marvin-backend
      image: http://my_registry_url:5000/marvin/backend:1.0

  frontend: *default-marvin-frontend

  frontend_versioned:
      << : *default-marvin-frontend
      image: http://my_registry_url:5000/marvin/frontend:1.0

networks:
  backend:
```

I'm new to docker in general, my main goal here is to have a simple, preferably one command (e.g `docker-compose build`), that will build and tag both my front end and back end images so that I can just execute `docker-compose push` to push those newly created images to my registry running on AWS. With that I also want to be able to override the latest version of those images in the registry while also adding a versioned image for backup purposes, in case I want to revisit any of those version in the future.

Then in the AWS EC2 machine I have another `docker-compose.yaml` file that just fetches the latest versions of both images and run their containers.

So to summarize I would develop the application on my local machine, then add the new version manually to the versioned services in the local `docker-compose.yaml` file, then run `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose push`; then ssh into my AWS machine and run `docker-compose up` to fetch the latest and newly updated images and run them.

This could later evolve into a CI/CD pipeline, but right now I'm taking baby steps and trying to get my image name to have a URL in it.

Thank you.

### Edit

I tried using a `.env` with `REGISTRY=http://my_registry_url:5000/marvin` and then using `image: "${REGISTRY}/frontend:latest"` or `image: "$${REGISTRY}/frontend:latest"` but that also didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `http://` part from your images.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Will accept the answer as soon as stack overflow lets me.